# Twitter, follows function

Tags: python, django, twitter

I've created a new model in database:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followed_by", blank=True)
```

And try to add 'follow' feature in my app:

```
class TweetDetailsView(View):
    def get(self, request, tweet_id):
        tweet = Tweet.objects.get(id=tweet_id)
        #likes
        is_liked = False
        if tweet.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            is_liked = True
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Tweet, id=self.kwargs['tweet_id'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        #follows
        is_followed = False
        if User.followed_by.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            is_followed = True
        return render(request, "twitter/tweet.html", locals())

def FollowUser(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.POST.get('user_id'))
    if User.followed_by.filter(id=request.user.id).exists:
        User.followed_by.remove(request.user)
        is_followed = False
    else:
        User.followed_by.add(request.user)
        is_followed = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tweet', args=[str(pk)]), locals())
```

However, i receive a info that: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'
How can i do that?
In case of likes, it worked.
Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Why are you accessing the `followed_by` property on the `User` class instead of the `user` variable defined above ?

Comment: Because then i've received: 'int' object has no attribute 'followed_by' or 'follows'

Comment: I am not saying this in a condescending way, but some red flags in your code makes me think that you should consider taking a good look at django's models documentation. In your code you call `.exists()` and then you try to access to the `.exists` property, which is a method, not a property. You are also trying to filter a property of your Class (`User.followed_by`) which is not filterable.
About your question, from what I understand I think you need to filter on `User.objects.filter(followed_by=user)` instead.